# Groovy with JavaFX GroovyObject not found in extractor for ObservableList

Tags: javafx, groovy, runtime-error, observablecollection, extractor

I'm trying to have an ObservableList of some type `User` which will notify any listchangelistener if one of the items stored in it had any of its values changed.

Though the callback always throws the exception:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ProxyGeneratorAdapter$InnerLoader.defineClass(ProxyGeneratorAdapter.java:926)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ProxyGeneratorAdapter.<init>(ProxyGeneratorAdapter.java:191)
    at groovy.util.ProxyGenerator.createAdapter(ProxyGenerator.java:233)
    at groovy.util.ProxyGenerator.instantiateDelegateWithBaseClass(ProxyGenerator.java:208)
    at groovy.util.ProxyGenerator.instantiateDelegateWithBaseClass(ProxyGenerator.java:192)
    at groovy.util.ProxyGenerator.instantiateDelegate(ProxyGenerator.java:184)
    at groovy.util.ProxyGenerator.instantiateDelegate(ProxyGenerator.java:180)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.asType(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:15768)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.asType(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:10859)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$53.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePojoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:935)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:926)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:181)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:604)
    at sample.Main$1.call(Main.groovy:36)
    at sample.Main$1.call(Main.groovy)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ElementObserver.attachListener(ElementObserver.java:79)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.doAdd(ObservableListWrapper.java:100)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.add(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:151)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.addAll(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:99)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.addAll(ObservableListBase.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:192)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.groovy:39)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovyObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:702)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:812)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:800)
    ... 47 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

I was able to reproduce the error with this example:

```
package sample

import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.beans.Observable
import javafx.collections.FXCollections
import javafx.collections.ObservableList
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox
import javafx.stage.Screen
import javafx.stage.Stage
import javafx.util.Callback

class Main extends Application {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(Main.class, args)

    }

    class User {
        String name
        User(String t){
            name = t
        }
    }

    @Override
    void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ObservableList<User> usersTest =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Callback<User, Observable[]>() {
                    @Override
                    Observable[] call(User o) {
                        return [o] as Observable
                    }
                })
        usersTest.addAll( new User("John"), new User("Jane"))

        ComboBox<User> cb = new ComboBox<>()
        cb.setItems(usersTest)

        cb.value = cb.items.first()

        def bounds = Screen.primary.bounds
        Scene scene = new Scene(cb, bounds.width, bounds.height)
        primaryStage.setScene(scene)
        primaryStage.show()
    }
}
```

I'm honestly a bit out of options as the error is as unhelpful as it gets.

Comment: I don't speak Groovy, but shouldn't that be `cb.setItems(usersTest)`? Other than that, are you sure the extractor has anything to do with the error message? This looks like you are trying to run this without Groovy being properly configured (it's complaining it can't find elementary Groovy classes).

Comment: That's the oddity about this issue. Groovy is perfectly fine configured, and runs well. The error points towards the "return [o] as Observable" when I follow the stacktrace as well. And yes you're right, I missed the `cb.setItems(usersTest)`. I'll edit it afterwards, the error persists though.

Comment: Ah, wait. A `User` is not an `Observable`, surely. You need to use a JavaFX property (e.g. `StringProperty`) and then return an array containing that property. In Java, you would do `return new Observable[] {o.nameProperty()};`, assuming [usual naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107).

Comment: Indeed that did fix the error, interestingly I also had to change `Observable` to `Observable[]`, so it was a plain syntax error.
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Well, yes, the `Callback` is a `Callback<User, Observable[]>`, after all. This is why strongly typed languages are better - you would have a nice, understandable, user-friendly compile error in Java, instead of the unhelpful runtime error ;).

Comment: But isn't googling and trying to fix your undescriptive error for 40 minutes part of the fun in programming? Also `nice, understandable, user-friendly compile error`, tell that to C++'s template errors :D